# TypeError: _this._transport.sendEvent is not a function

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I have successfully provisioned Device, I am using X509 certs for provisioning and its working fine. Now I want to send device messages to IoT hub, so I have created a separate class DeviceHelper, but I am getting this error. Can somebody please help?
TypeError: _this._transport.sendEvent is not a function

Code for Device Provisioning

```html
var fs = require('fs');
var DeviceHelper = require('./device-helper');
var Transport = require('azure-iot-provisioning-device-http').Http;
var X509Security = require('azure-iot-security-x509').X509Security;
var ProvisioningDeviceClient = require('azure-iot-provisioning- 
device').ProvisioningDeviceClient;
// Register the device.  Do not force a re-registration.
        deviceClient.register(function (err, result) {
           if (err) {
               that.setProvisionStatus(PROVISION_STATUS.ERROR);
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('registration succeeded');
            that.assignedHub = result.assignedHub;
            console.log('assigned hub=' + result.assignedHub);
            console.log('deviceId=' + result.deviceId);
            var deviceHelper = new DeviceHelper(that.deviceId, that.assignedHub, deviceCert, Transport);
            deviceHelper.sendEvent();
        }
    });
```

**DeviceHelper code:**

```html
   

 

var Device = require('azure-iot-device');
    var Client = Device.Client;
    var X509AuthenticationProvider = Device.X509AuthenticationProvider;
    var Message = Device.Message;
    var Http = Device.Http;

    var client = {};
    class DeviceHelper {

      constructor(deviceId, hubName, security, transport) {
        client = Client.fromAuthenticationProvider(X509AuthenticationProvider.fromX509Options(
          deviceId, hubName, security
        ),transport);
      }

      print(err, res) {
        if (err) console.log(err.toString());
        if (res) console.log(res.statusCode + ' ' + res.statusMessage);
      }

      sendEvent() {
    // Error on this line
        client.sendEvent(new Message('hello world'), this.print);
      }
    }

    module.exports = DeviceHelper;
```

Console log of the issue:

```
TypeError: _this._transport.sendEvent is not a function
index.js:23
message:"_this._transport.sendEvent is not a function"
stack:"TypeError: _this._transport.sendEvent is not a function\n at D:\Working\Brahma\web-communicator\server\iot-agent\node_modules\azure-iot-device\lib\client.js:216:30\n at retryOperation (D:\Working\Brahma\web-communicator\server\iot-agent\node_modules\azure-iot-device\node_modules\azure-iot-common\lib\retry_operation.js:31:13)\n at RetryOperation.retry (D:\Working\Brahma\web-communicator\server\iot-agent\node_modules\azure-iot-device\node_modules\azure-iot-common\lib\retry_operation.js:57:9)\n at Client.sendEvent (server\iot-agent\node_modules\azure-iot-device\lib\client.js:214:17)\n at DeviceHelper.sendEvent (\device-helper.js:22:12)\n at \iot-device.js:99:30\n at D:\Working\Brahma\web-communicator\server\iot-agent\node_modules\azure-iot-provisioning-device\lib\x509_registration.js:50:33\n at constructor._onEnter (D:\Working\Brahma\web-communicator\server\iot...
proto:Error {constructor: , name: "TypeError", message: "", …}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transport that you are sending to your deviceHelper constructor appears to be a *provisioning* transport.  I think you want to send a device client transport.  Your code snippet for the deviceHelper module does a require on a device transport.  That is the kind of transport that has a send.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [azure-iot-sdk-node/device/samples/simple_sample_device.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/device/samples/simple_sample_device.js), it provides a nice example on how to send a message using the **SDK**.

Hope it helps!